# ComboBox SelectedItem value binding will not set to anything other than null

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to create a MVVM program. When a radio button is pressed it will deselect the other radio buttons and change the contents of a combo box to different values depending on the radio button pressed. Then it will use the value selected to set a string. The problem that I am having is that the value bound to the SelectedItem is always null and it throws an error. How can I fix this problem?

As a side not the combobox does display the entire list correctly so the binding for ItemsSource is working correctly and the SelectedIndex is updating correctly as well it is only the SelectedItem that is not seeming to bind right.

Now that I am thinking about it with the selectedindex working I could use that value to select from the appropriate string list, but I would like to know what is happening and why I can't use SelectedItem and if there is a way to used SelectedItem.

The following code is hopefully a simplified version of what is happening in my code I hope I didn't miss anything.

XAML

```
<RadioButton Grid.Column="0" Content="List1" IsChecked="{Binding Path=TypeList1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<RadioButton Grid.Column="1" Content="List2" IsChecked="{Binding Path=TypeList2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Content="List3" IsChecked="{Binding Path=TypeList3, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

<ComboBox Margin="5" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MySource}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=MySelectedIndex,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          />
```

C#

```
Class MyClass
{
    private list<string> _listType;
    private list<string> _mySource;
    private bool _typeList1;
    private bool _typeList2;
    private bool _typeList3;
    private ComboBoxItem _mySelectedItem;
    private int _mySelectedIndex;
    
    public list<string> ListType
    {
        get{ return _listType;}
        set{ _listType=value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ListType));
    }

    public bool TypeList1
    {
        get{return _typeList1;}
        set
        {
            _typeList1=value; 
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TypeList1));
            if(value==true)
            {
                MySource=List1;
                TypeList2=false;
                TypeList3=false;
            }   
        }
    }
    public bool TypeList2
    {
        get{return _typeList2;}
        set
        {
            _typeList2=value; 
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TypeList2));
            if(value==true)
            {
                MySource=List2;
                TypeList1=false;
                TypeList3=false;
            }   
        }
    }
    public bool TypeList3
    {
        get{return _typeList3;}
        set
        {
            _typeList3=value; 
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TypeList3));
            if(value==true)
            {
                MySource=List3;
                TypeList2=false;
                TypeList1=false;
            }   
        }
    }
    
    public list<string> MySource
    {
        get{ return _mySource;}
        set{ _mySource=value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MySource));
    }
    public ComboBoxItem MySelectedItem
    {
        get{ return _mySelectedItem;}
        set{ _mySelectedItem=value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MySelectedItem));
    }

    public int MySelectedIndex
    {
        get{ return _mySelectedIndex;}
        set{_mySelectedIndex=value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MySelectedIndex));
    }

    public List<string> List1=new List<string> {"List1Val1", "List1Val2", "List1Val3",};
    public List<string> List2=new List<string> {"List2Val1", "List2Val2", "List2Val3","List2Val4"};
    public List<string> List3=new List<string> {"List3Val1", "List3Val2", "List3Val3",};
    
    public MyClass()
    {
        MySource= new List<string>();
        ListType= new List<string>();
    }
    
    public void MyFunction()
    {
        string mySelectedValueFromComboBox= MySelectedItem.content.ToString();// where the error happens when the code is run.
    }
}
```

The error that happens is:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

FileName.mySelectedValueFromComboBox.get returned null.

What I expected is the string value in MyFunction get set to the string value of the selected ComboBoxItem.

In a different part of my code, I defined the ComboBoxItems inside the XAML instead of in the C# and this method worked there.

Comment: Your items are strings, so `ComboBoxItem MySelectedItem` should better be `string MySelectedItem`

Comment: As far as I understand SelectedItem in the ComboBox returns a ComboBoxItem is that not right?

Comment: NO. It is an item of source collection which corresponds to the selected ComboBoxItem.

Comment: Just changed it to a string and that worked thank you  
@KlausGütter feel like an idiot now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Klaus Gütter and emoacht in the comments I was able to change the ComboBoxItem to a string this allowed me to run the code and give me the correct output expected.